# Loginstatus not working while i want to logout .. it remains logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loginstatus not working while i want to logout in remains logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417080/loginstatus-not-working-while-i-want-to-logout-in-remains-logout)

```
I am studding a tutorial on asp.net mvc which name is MvcMusicStore. I am creating MvcBookStore For login and logout i use the facility of ASP.net configuration. I am successful in login but unsuccessful in logout using loginstatus from toolbox.
```

Here i am giving some of my codes that's are related with login and logout:

In my controllers folder i have created StoreManagerController.cs where i use
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] inside of namespace MvcBookStore.Controllers.
format is given below:

```
namespace MvcBookStore.Controllers
{
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
  {
       // code goes here...
  }  
}
```

Now in the model folder i have created AccountModel.cs file and below i am giving the codes that's are necessary:

```
namespace MvcBookStore.Models
{
    #region Services
public interface IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
    void SignOut();
}

public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        ValidationUtil.ValidateRequiredStringValue(userName, "userName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

The above code is automatically added when an asp.net mvc website is created. I have not change anything.
I want to use LoginStatus facilities on visual studio 2010 . Because it automatically find the logout url. Tis is why i add it in my View/StoreManager/Index.aspx in a position. The code is given below:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup ="true" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcBookStore.Models.Album>>" %>
<script runat="server">
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
       Response.Redirect("/View/Home/Index.aspx");    
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <h2>Index&nbsp;
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
            onloggingout="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut" 
            LogoutAction="Redirect" />
    </h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AlbumId }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AlbumId })%>
            </td>
            <td><%: Html.Truncate(item.Title, 25) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.Truncate(item.Artist.Name, 25) %></td>
            <td><%: item.Genre.Name %></td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>

    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>

    </p>
    <p>
          <a href="/Control/ordercontrol.aspx" > control order</a>

    </p>

    </form>

</asp:Content>
```

every thing is ok but when i click on the logout link it does nothing just refresh itself.

Comment: You need to learn how MVC works.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417080/loginstatus-not-working-while-i-want-to-logout-in-remains-logout**

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix ASP.Net WebForms server controls with MVC.
Don't do that; it won't work.

Instead, use MVC actions and logic.